# "Call to a member function getIsInStock() on null" with getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()

Tags: magento2, product, stock, magento-2.1, service-contract

I try to access stock data for a product, using

```
$product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()
```

and receive the following error on this line

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getIsInStock() on null.

Obviously the `stock_item` extension attribute was not loaded. `$product` comes from the product repository and has been loaded with `$productRepository->getList()`.

How can I get products **with stock information** from the product repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible in a reasonable way as of Magento 2.1

You can use the stock registry and pass each item of the result to `Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock::assignStatusToProduct()`.

But this results in a single database query for each product. In my tests with 2000 products, this takes three times longer than loading the collection directly with `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status::addStockDataToCollection()`

To optimize the stock registry, one would have to add a method to fetch multiple stock items at once and assign them to an array of products.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the productRepository you can do this:

`$this->_productRepository->getById($product->getId())->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getIsInStock();`

Comment: But this will trigger another full product load, right? The repository methods are slow enough already, triggering the classic "load in a a loop" is not an option for me.

Comment: Correct. You can't call `isInStock()` on the items, since they'll always return 1, even if they're not in stock and you also can't use `getStockData()` since that'll return NULL. As far as I know stock data isn't included in the product list items.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably resort to collections again for more flexibility

Comment: Alternatively you can use the `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockItemRepositoryInterface` to just load the stock item seperately, like this:

`$this->_stockItemRepository->get($product->getQuantityAndStockStatus())->getIsInStock()`

Comment: where i can find method `getQuantityAndStockStatus` define?

Comment: I need to check stock status whether the product is in stock or out of stok

Comment: I m  using I am using Magento\Catalog\Model\Product.php in my block to get the product collection